# How to speedup iteration in List

Tags: java, string, performance, list, loops

I have a `List<String>` and there is almost 20,000 records in it(and may be more)...
I need to iterate over this list and it takes almost 3 minutes...

Here is my block of code:

```
for (String string : list) {
    response += string;
    response += "/t";
}
```

I have two questions:

1. long time is for List iteration or for operation on each item?
2. depending on answer to the question 1 how can i speed up this operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The poor performance is more likely to be your use of string concatenation.  Use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Map if it is applicable. Here is a link for a very common Java objects and how much their operations cost using Big-O notation.

http://objectissues.blogspot.com/2006/11/big-o-notation-and-java-constant-time.html

Comment: The data structure is not the problem (see my answer).